# tread tire in snow + animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

I would like animate and render a car driving in a snow, so my main issue for the moment is to have the tread of the tire (and sometime a rough mark) during the car is driving.

See picture bellow [image]

I was thinking do two planes, one with the snow and the tread mapped where I want on the plane, And an other plane WITHOUT mark on the ground. And play with the opacity of the two plane in After Effect or in blender with mask . But I have no idea how to unwrapped the tread mark exactly where I want, AND I have to calculate my scene twice...

Any other ideas are welcome :)

Render engine : Cycle

Comment: use dynamic paint to get something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2370Ud4hFW0 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFWAjyaM1Hs or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-t7mx8ZH_k  more info here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:MiikaH/GSoC-2011-DynamicPaint

Comment: Thank you ! I never really use this tool but it seems to do what I want !