# Wheels leaving trails when moving?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

I'm creating a Martian habitat animation for a school project and was wondering how to make my Mars Rover leave trails on the surface when it is driving around?[image]

Comment: do a search for [**dynamic paint**](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=dynamic+paint+blender)

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39921/tread-tire-in-snow-animation)

Comment: The basics of dynamic paint: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcWXFtnh2bk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could animate a displacement map that reveals itself as the wheels pass. If you take your UV from the road, add all the trails, and then add a mask (maybe in after effects, then you would have an animated texture) to reveal them when needed. 
This would only work if you already have the animation of the vehicle.